# Извлечение псевдорандомной записи из MySQL, не попадающей в диапазон значений

Tags: php, mysql, sql, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте.

Встала задача - извлечь псевдорандомную запись из БД, однако, её ID Не должен попадать в диапазон имеющихся (к примеру, использованных ранее).

Получился вот такой вот "алгоритм".

```
    $ids = explode(',',$_SESSION['vars']);
    if (count($ids) == 4){
        $_SESSION['vars'] = '0';
        die();
    }

    $get = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `quests`");
    $get = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $cnt = $get['count'];
    while(!$flag){
        $rnd = rand(1,$cnt);
        if (in_array($rnd,$ids)){
            $flag = false;
            echo 'Элемент с ID '.$rnd.' существует! <br>';
        }else{
            $flag = true;
        }
    }
    $get = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `quests` WHERE `id` = ".$rnd);
    $get = $get->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $vars.=','.$rnd;
    $_SESSION['vars'] = $vars;
```

`
Вопрос следующий: возможно ли реализовать это как то средствами только SQL?

Comment: Вопрос лишь в том, в каком количестве и где у вас id которых быть не дложно. Обычный `select * from quests where id not in(1,5,10,76) order by rand() limit 1` в принципе даст нужный результат, но вот оптимально ли это в вашем случае

Comment: @Mike, для ясности был приложен код. Иды использованных записей лежат в сессии простой строкой. 
Т.к. записи извлекаются поочередно по одной, количество их уже не принципиально, за тем, что бы не ушло что либо лишнее будем следить отдельно.
И спасибо, попробую Ваш вариант.

Comment: Я про количество спросил, потому что длина запроса в принципе ограничена и использование сотен ID внутри `not in` может быть проблемой. Да и `order by rand()` прочитает всю таблицу. Выборка конкретной записи по заранее известному ID на порядок быстрее. Правда ваш текущий код требует что бы в таблице присутствовали все ID строго от 1 до кол-во-записей

Comment: @Mike, в `not in` будет не более 14 ID. Записей в таблице от силы - пара сотен. 
И как он ограничен? Что он требует? Если изначально извлекается счетчик кол-ва записей в таблице, и на основе него уже и генерируется рандомное число, как предел.
Я что то упустил, видимо?

Comment: Ну 14 это не страшно и пара сотен в общем не критично. Хотя и медленнее чем ваш текущий алгоритм. А в вашем текущем проблема будет если в базе есть записи 1,2,3, и потом сразу 7,8,9 вам count() даст только 6 значит вы не сможете сгенерить номера 7,8,9. И если rand выдаст число 5, то цикл поиска числа завершится, а запись с ID=5 в базе не найдется. Так что для защиты от дырок в нумерации лучше брать max(id) вместо count() и select делать внутри цикла поиска подходящего числа.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по коду вы в контексте сессии храните ранее полученные Id через запятую, а потом получаете новую.
Если у вас не будет более 15 обработанных идов в сессии, почему бы не получить из базы ВСЕ 15 идов одним запросом и хранить их в сессии?

Т.е. запросом вида:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id SEPARATOR ',') FROM quests ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 30 /*с запасом*/
```

Получаем 15 случайных записей из quests.
записываем их в контекст сессии в "необработанные", затем по одному айдишнику выбираем и записываем в обработанные. **Не обращаясь к БД за новым Id!** 
Правда придётся обратиться за другими полями таблицы quests, но уже по индексу - а это уже мелочи по сравнению с сортировкой по rand().

Если вдруг нам этих Id'ов в сессии не хватит - сделать новый запрос за следующей пачкой. Запрос вида:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Id SEPARATOR ',') FROM quests 
WHERE Id NOT IN (/*список обработанных Id'ов*/) ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 30
```

И далее по кругу, если сессия "сильно затянется".
Таким образом , при условии, что в сессии обработается записей меньше, чем размер пачки, сортировка ORDER BY rand() выполнится **только один раз.**